# ^PgUp, ^PgDn, ^End, do not work, in Groovy

Tags: keyboard, cinnamon

All keys work fine without a modifier key. In all applications I have tested, Ctrl-PgUp, PgDn, and End are null--no effect on any program. Contrary to various answers I've found in searches, this is only on the **non**-numeric keypad keys. The ones on the numeric keypad work fine, if NumLock is off.

Oddly, Ctrl-Home works, but not Ctrl-End. I don't know the mechanics, but it's odd that whatever software is confused would treat them differently.

Groovy, installed yesterday, switched to Cinnamon desktop, and fully updated. System is Intel NUC. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. I had installed QRedshift without looking at its shortcuts. Turns out that by default that applet seizes the keystrokes in question.